# AsyncStorage com chaves dinâmicas não salva os valores

Tags: array, react-native, asyncstorage

Estou tentando fazer uma lista onde o usuário vê todas as keys que ele salvou no app e quando ele clicar nelas vai ocorrer o load do preset que ele fez com base na key. Estou recebendo o erro:

> TypeError: Attempted to assign to readonly property

```js
    state = {
        dateiName: 'Mrx',
        dateiDatum: '',
        dateiAuto: '',
        dateien: [],
        dateiselected: '',
        arr: []
    }

    async componentDidMount() {
        var listData = [];
        let keys = await AsyncStorage.getAllKeys();
        keys.forEach(async function(inKey) {
          const person = await AsyncStorage.getItem(inKey);
          person.key = inKey;
          listData.push(person);
        });
        this.setState({arr: listData})
        console.log(arr)
      };

     saveData(nome) {
        var nomeKey = nome
        AsyncStorage.setItem(nomeKey,JSON.stringify(this.state.arr))
     }

    displayData = async () => {
        try{
            const keys = await AsyncStorage.getAllKeys();
            return keys
        }
        catch(error) {
            alert(error)
        }
    }


    removeData = async () => {
        try {
          await AsyncStorage.clear()
          alert('Storage successfully cleared!')
        } catch (e) {
          alert('Failed to clear the async storage.')
        }
      }

    render(){
        return (
            //aqui vem algumas coisas irrelevantes antes
            <>
                <ScrollView>
                    <FlatList
                        data={this.state.arr}
                        renderItem={({item}) => (
                            <View>
                                <TouchableOpacity>
                                    <Text>{item}</Text>
                                </TouchableOpacity>
                            </View>
                        )}
                        //keyExtractor={item => item.id}
                    />
                </ScrollView>
                <TouchableOpacity
                    onPress={this.saveData(this.state.dateiName)}
                    style={styles.botaomenor}>
                </TouchableOpacity>
            </>
        );
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Olá! Não é ideal você colocar o async no componentDidMount você poderia criar uma função assíncrona e chamar ela lá dentro. Acredito que o erro é por conta do:

```
person.key = inKey;
```

Acho que esse resultado é somente leitura mesmo você usando como objeto. Você não está usando este atributo em canto nenhum só dentro deste escopo então nem é necessário cria-lo pode retirar e usar algo assim:

```
listData.push({
  key: inKey,
  person,
});
```

Uma observação, não sei como está sua lógica na hora de salvar os dados, mas ao invés de salvar cada usuário individualmente no asyncstorage não seria melhor salvar um array de usuários lá?